# How can I sort a text file from number of occupied lines?

Tags: text, sort

How could I sort a text files from number of ocupied lines?

From:

`He spoke to her, saying, "Dear child, can my servant and I find shelter for the night in this little house?"

"Oh, yes," said the girl in a sad voice, "You certainly can, but I do not advise you to do so. Do not go inside."
"Why not?" asked the prince.

The girl sighed and said, "My stepmother practices evil arts, and she does not like strangers."

Then he realized that he had come to a witch's house, but because it was dark, and he could go no further, he entered. In any event, he was not afraid.
The old woman was sitting in an armchair by the fire. She looked at the stranger with her red eyes. "Good evening," she croaked,

pretending to be quite friendly. "Sit down and rest."
She blew into the coals on which she was cooking something in a small pot. The daughter warned the two to be cautious, to eat nothing, and to drink nothing, for the old woman brewed evil drinks. They slept soundly until early morning.

After traveling about for a long time they came to a town where there was a beautiful but proud princess. She had made it known that she would marry any man who could ask her a riddle that she could not solve. However, if she solved it his head would be cut off. She had three days to think about it, but was so clever that she always solved the riddle that she had been given before the deadline. When the prince arrived nine men had already died in this manner. However, he was blinded by her great beauty and was willing to risk his life for it.´

To:

´After traveling about for a long time they came to a town where there was a beautiful but proud princess. She had made it known that she would marry any man who could ask her a riddle that she could not solve. However, if she solved it his head would be cut off. She had three days to think about it, but was so clever that she always solved the riddle that she had been given before the deadline. When the prince arrived nine men had already died in this manner. However, he was blinded by her great beauty and was willing to risk his life for it.

pretending to be quite friendly. "Sit down and rest."
She blew into the coals on which she was cooking something in a small pot. The daughter warned the two to be cautious, to eat nothing, and to drink nothing, for the old woman brewed evil drinks. They slept soundly until early morning.

Then he realized that he had come to a witch's house, but because it was dark, and he could go no further, he entered. In any event, he was not afraid.
The old woman was sitting in an armchair by the fire. She looked at the stranger with her red eyes. "Good evening," she croaked,

"Oh, yes," said the girl in a sad voice, "You certainly can, but I do not advise you to do so. Do not go inside."
"Why not?" asked the prince.

He spoke to her, saying, "Dear child, can my servant and I find shelter for the night in this little house?"

The girl sighed and said, "My stepmother practices evil arts, and she does not like strangers."´

Comment: When I copy and paste your text then I get 6 lines, some of which are very long. So the question can be rephrased to _"How do I sort lines by their length?"_, or do I miss something? Please also consider that 300 times the letter `l` may occupy fewer lines than 200 times the letter `m` when a proportional font is used.

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917576/sort-a-text-file-by-line-length-including-spaces

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Awk version 4.0+

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {RS=""; ORS="\n\n"} 
  {a[$0] = length($0)} 
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (i in a) print i
  }
' file.txt
```

Note that this sorts on number of characters, including punctuation and whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Used this not so optimized command line:

```
cat -n notes.txt | sort -rn | head -6 >> result.txt && \ 
cat -n notes.txt | sort -rn | tail -5 | sort -n | head -3 | sort -rn >> result.txt && \ 
cat -n notes.txt | sort -rn | tail -5 | sort -n | tail -2 >> result.txt && \ 
sed -i 's/^\s*[[:digit:]]*\s*//g' result.txt
```

Information: It splits the whole texts into parts and then puts sort and puts them together and removes the line numbers used to sort them.

Results:

After traveling about for a long time they came to a town where there was a beautiful but proud princess. She had made it known that she would marry any man who could ask her a riddle that she could not solve. However, if she solved it his head would be cut off. She had three days to think about it, but was so clever that she always solved the riddle that she had been given before the deadline. When the prince arrived nine men had already died in this manner. However, he was blinded by her great beauty and was willing to risk his life for it.

pretending to be quite friendly. "Sit down and rest." She blew into the coals on which she was cooking something in a small pot. The daughter warned the two to be cautious, to eat nothing, and to drink nothing, for the old woman brewed evil drinks. They slept soundly until early morning.

Then he realized that he had come to a witch's house, but because it was dark, and he could go no further, he entered. In any event, he was not afraid. The old woman was sitting in an armchair by the fire. She looked at the stranger with her red eyes. "Good evening," she croaked,

"Oh, yes," said the girl in a sad voice, "You certainly can, but I do not advise you to do so. Do not go inside." "Why not?" asked the prince.

He spoke to her, saying, "Dear child, can my servant and I find shelter for the night in this little house?"

The girl sighed and said, "My stepmother practices evil arts, and she does not like strangers."

Comment: Those `head -6` and `tail -5` commands make me suspicious that this solution will work for exactly 6 paragraphs. Is that so?

Comment: Yes. OP don't seem to say it's not a one of case. So I guess this will do for now.